# MonadBaseControl: how to lift ThreadGroup

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

In [threads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads) package in module [`Control.Concurrent.Thread.Group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread-Group.html) there is a function `forkIO`:

```
forkIO :: ThreadGroup -> IO α -> IO (ThreadId, IO (Result α))
```

I'd like to lift it using `MonadBaseControl` from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html). Here is my attempt:

```
fork :: (MonadBase IO m) => TG.ThreadGroup -> m α -> m (ThreadId, m (Result α))
fork tg action = control (\runInBase -> TG.forkIO tg (runInBase action))
```

and here is the error messsage:

```
Couldn't match type `(ThreadId, IO (Result (StM m α)))'
              with `StM m (ThreadId, m (Result α))'
Expected type: IO (StM m (ThreadId, m (Result α)))
  Actual type: IO (ThreadId, IO (Result (StM m α)))
In the return type of a call of `TG.forkIO'
In the expression: TG.forkIO tg (runInBase action)
In the first argument of `control', namely
  `(\ runInBase -> TG.forkIO tg (runInBase action))'
```

What to change to make the types match?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the `IO a` argument to `forkIO`. To fork an `m a` action in `IO` we'd need a way to run an `m a` to an `IO a`. To do this, we could try to make the class of monads that have a `runBase :: MonadBase b m => m a -> b a` method, but very few interesting transformers can provide that. If we consider for example the `StateT` transformer, it could figure out how to run something in the base monad with `runStateT` if it's first given an opportunity to observe its own state.

```
runFork :: Monad m => StateT s m a -> StateT s m (m b)
runFork x = do
    s <- get
    return $ do
        (a, s') <- runStateT x s
        return a
```

This suggests the type `runForkBase :: MonadBase b m => m a -> m (b a)`, which we will settle on for the following type class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Monad.Base

class (MonadBase b m) => MonadRunForkBase b m | m -> b where
    runForkBase :: m a -> m (b a)
```

I added the word `Fork` to the name to emphasize that the future state changes will not in general be shared between the two futures. For this reason, the few interesting transformers like `WriterT` that could have provided a `runBase` only provide an uninteresting `runBase`; they produce side effects that will never be observable.

We can write something like `fork` for anything with the limited form of lowering provided by a `MonadRunForkBase IO m` instance. I'm going to `lift` the normal `forkIO` from base rather than the one from [threads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads), which you can do the same way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Concurrent

forkInIO :: (MonadRunForkBase IO m) => m () -> m ThreadId
forkInIO action = runForkBase action >>= liftBase . forkIO
```

#### Instances

This raises the question, "What transformers can we provide `MonadRunForkBase` instances for"? Straight off the bat, we can trivially provide them for any of the base monads that have `MonadBase` instances

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Identity
import GHC.Conc.Sync (STM)

instance MonadRunForkBase [] [] where runForkBase = return 
instance MonadRunForkBase IO IO where runForkBase = return
instance MonadRunForkBase STM STM where runForkBase = return
instance MonadRunForkBase Maybe Maybe where runForkBase = return
instance MonadRunForkBase Identity Identity where runForkBase = return
```

For transformers, it's usually easier to build up functionality like this step-by-step. Here's the class of transformers that can run a fork in the immediately underlying monad.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

class (MonadTrans t) => MonadTransRunFork t where
    runFork :: Monad m => t m a -> t m (m a)
```

We can provide a default implementation for running all the way down in the base

```
runForkBaseDefault :: (Monad (t m), MonadTransRunFork t, MonadRunForkBase b m) =>
                      t m a -> t m (b a)
runForkBaseDefault = (>>= lift . runForkBase) . runFork
```

This lets us complete out a `MonadRunForkBase` instance for `StateT` in two steps. First, we'll use our `runFork` from above to make a `MonadTransRunFork` instance

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy as State

instance MonadTransRunFork (State.StateT s) where
    runFork x = State.get >>= return . liftM fst . State.runStateT x
```

Then we'll use the default to provide a `MonadRunForkBase` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (MonadRunForkBase b m) => MonadRunForkBase b (State.StateT s m) where
    runForkBase = runForkBaseDefault
```

We can do the same thing for `RWS`

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Lazy as RWS

instance (Monoid w) => MonadTransRunFork (RWS.RWST r w s) where
    runFork x = do
        r <- RWS.ask
        s <- RWS.get
        return $ do 
            (a, s', w') <- RWS.runRWST x r s
            return a

instance (MonadRunForkBase b m, Monoid w) => MonadRunForkBase b (RWS.RWST r w s m) where
    runForkBase = runForkBaseDefault
```

#### MonadBaseControl

Unlike `MonadRunForkBase` which we developed in the previous two sections, the `MonadBaseControl` from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html) doesn't have baked in the assumption "future state changes will not in general be shared between the two futures". `MonadBaseContol` and `control` make an effort to restore the state from branching in control structures with `restoreM :: StM m a -> m a`. This doesn't present a problem for the `forkIO` from base; using `forkIO` is an example provided in the `MonadBaseControl` documentation. This will be a slight problem for the [`forkIO` from threads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads-0.5.1.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread-Group.html) because of the extra `m (Result a)` returned.

The `m (Result a)` we want will actually be returned as an `IO (Result (StM m a))`. We can get rid of the `IO` and replace it with an `m` with `liftBase`, leaving us with `m (Result (StM m a))`. We could convert an `StM m a` into an `m a` that restores state and then returns `a` with `restoreM`, but it is stuck inside a `Result ~ Either SomeException`. `Either l` is a functor, so we can apply `restoreM` everywhere inside it, simplifying the type to `m (Result (m a))`. `Either l` is also `Traversable`, and for any `Traversable` `t` we can always swap it inside a `Monad` or `Applicative` with `sequenceA :: t (f a) -> f (t a)`. In this case, we can use the special purpose `mapM` which is a combination of `fmap` and `sequenceA` with only a `Monad` constraint. This would give `m (m (Result a))`, and the `m`s would be flattened together by a join in the Monad or simply using `>>=`. This gives rise to

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Thread
import qualified Control.Concurrent.Thread.Group as TG

import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control

import Data.Functor
import Data.Traversable
import Prelude hiding (mapM)

fork :: (MonadBaseControl IO m) =>
        TG.ThreadGroup -> m a -> m (ThreadId, m (Result a))
fork tg action = do
    (tid, r) <- liftBaseWith (\runInBase -> TG.forkIO tg (runInBase action))    
    return (tid, liftBase r >>= mapM restoreM)
```

When we run the `m (Result a)` in the original thread, it will copy the state from the forked thread to the original thread, which may be useful. If you want to restore the state of the main thread after reading the `Result` you'll need to capture it first. `checkpoint` will capture the entire state and return an action to restore it.

```
checkpoint :: MonadBaseControl b m => m (m ())
checkpoint = liftBaseWith (\runInBase -> runInBase (return ()))
             >>= return . restoreM
```

A complete example will show what happens to the state from two threads. Both threads get the state from when the `fork` happened regardless of efforts to modify the state in the other thread. When we wait for the result in the main thread, the state in the main thread is set to the state from the forked thread. We can get the main thread's state back by running the action created by `checkpoint`.

```
import Control.Monad.State hiding (mapM)

example :: (MonadState String m, MonadBase IO m, MonadBaseControl IO m) => m ()
example = do    
    get >>= liftBase . putStrLn
    tg <- liftBase TG.new
    (_, getResult) <- fork tg (get >>= put . ("In Fork:" ++)  >> return 7)
    get >>= put . ("In Main:" ++) 
    revert <- checkpoint
    result <- getResult
    (liftBase . print) result
    get >>= liftBase . putStrLn
    revert
    get >>= liftBase . putStrLn

main = do
    runStateT example "Initial"
    return ()
```

This outputs

```
Initial
Right 7
In Fork:Initial
In Main:Initial
```

Comment: Thanks for some clarification. Is there a way to get this done with MonadBaseControl only, without any new special typeclasses?

Comment: @GracjanPolak I added a section on `MonadBaseControl`.

Comment: Great! Seems like this is what I needed. Can you reorder sections in your answer so that direct answer is top and discussion follows later?