# MonadBaseControl: how to lift simpleHTTP from Happstack?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

How to use [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) to lift [`simpleHTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server/docs/Happstack-Server-SimpleHTTP.html#v:simpleHTTP) function defined in [happstack-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server)?

Current type of `simpleHTTP`:

```
simpleHTTP :: ToMessage a 
           => Conf -> ServerPartT IO a -> IO ()
```

Expected type of `simpleHTTPLifted`:

```
simpleHTTPLifted :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, ToMessage a)
                 => Conf -> ServerPartT m a -> m ()
```

My current attempt (does not compile):

```
simpleHTTPLifted conf action =
   liftBaseWith (\runInBase ->
              let
                  fixTypes :: UnWebT m a -> UnWebT IO a
                  fixTypes c = runInBase c
              in simpleHTTP conf (mapServerPartT fixTypes action)
           )
```

Note that similar puzzle is in my related question: [MonadBaseControl: how to lift ThreadGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704615/monadbasecontrol-how-to-lift-threadgroup)

I'd like to understand how to in general lift such functions and what are usual steps taken when presented with such a type puzzle?

EDIT: I guess I need a function of type `(StM m a -> a)`. `restoreM` is pretty close, but does not make it. I've also found an ugly version of `fixTypes`:

```
fixTypes :: UnWebT m a -> UnWebT IO a
fixTypes c = do
    x <- newIORef undefined
    _ <- runInBase (c >>= liftBase . writeIORef x)
    readIORef x
```

This relies on IO being the base monad which is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can lift this in general for any `MonadBaseControl IO m`. There are some `m`s for which we can.

#### In General

`UnWebT m` is isomorphic to [`WebT m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.3.9/docs/Happstack-Server-Internal-Monads.html#t:WebT) which has a [`MonadTransControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html) instance. You can convert to and from `WebT` with `mkWebT :: UnWebT m a -> WebT m a` and `ununWebT :: WebT m a -> UnWebT m a`.

`MonadBaseControl` is a fancy wrapper around a stack of `MonadTransControl` transformers that flattens the stack so that running and restoring state happens all the way down the stack and all the way back up it again. You can understand `MonadBaseControl` by understanding `MonadTransControl`, which I'll repeat briefly here:

```
class MonadTrans t => MonadTransControl t where
  data StT t :: * -> *
  liftWith :: Monad m => (Run t -> m a) -> t m a
  restoreT :: Monad m => m (StT t a) -> t m a

type Run t = forall n b. Monad n => t n b -> n (StT t b)
```

The class says with `liftWith`, "I'll provide a temporary way to run `t m`s in `m`, which you can use to build actions in `m`, which I will in turn run." The `StT` type of the result says, "the results of the `t m` things I run in `m` for you aren't going to be generally available in `t m`; I need to save my state somewhere, and you have to give me a chance to restore my state if you want the results."

Another way of saying approximately the same thing is, "I can temporarily unwrap the base monad". The question of implementing `fixTypes` is reduced to "Given that we can temporarily unwrap a `WebT` from an `m` and can temporarily unwrap an `m` from `IO`, can we permanently unwrap an `m` from an `IO`?" for which the answer, barring the capabilities of `IO`, is almost certainly "no".

#### IO Tricks

I suspect that there exist `m`s such that the "ugly" `fixTypes` will do horrible things like never call `writeIORef` and thus return `undefined` or execute code asynchronously and therefore call `writeIORef` after `readIORef`. I'm not sure. This is made complicated to reason about due to the possibility that the action created by `liftBaseWith` is never used in such degenerate cases.

#### For Comonads

There should be a way to lift `simpleHttp` without `IO` tricks precisely when the state of the monad `m` is a [`Comonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html) and therefore has a function `extract :: StM m a -> a`. For example, this would be the case for `StateT s m` which essentially has `StM s a ~ (s, a)`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Happstack.Server.SimpleHTTP

import Control.Comonad
import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control

simpleHTTPLifted :: forall m a. (MonadBaseControl IO m, Comonad (StM m), ToMessage a)
                 => Conf -> ServerPartT m a -> m ()
simpleHTTPLifted conf action =
    liftBaseWith (\runInBase ->
        let
            fixTypes :: UnWebT m b -> UnWebT IO b
            fixTypes = fmap extract . runInBase
        in simpleHTTP conf (mapServerPartT fixTypes action)
    )
```

In practice this isn't very useful because the `newtype`s defined in the older versions of monad-control don't have `Comonad` instances and the type synonymns in the newer versions of monad-control make no effort to have the result as the last type argument. For example, in the newest version of monad-control `type StT (StateT s) a = (a, s)` .

Comment: Can you change the order of presentation? Comonads should go first as direct response, everything else as supportive discussion of the problem.