# Getting parallel IO while accounting for failure

Tags: haskell

I'm making several API calls that are encapsulated in a type alias:

```
type ConnectT a = EitherT String (RWST ConnectReader ConnectWriter ConnectState IO) a
```

Here's a simplified version of a function which connects to two separate APIs:

```
connectBoth :: ConnectT ()
connectBoth = do
    a <- connectAPI SomeAPI someFunction
    b <- connectAPI OtherAPI otherFunction
    connectAPI OtherAPI (b `sendTo` a)
```

The final call in `connectBoth` is very time sensitive (and the transactions are of a financial nature). I figure `a` and `b` could be evaluated in parallel, and with lazy IO I should be able to do this:

```
    b <- a `par` connectAPI OtherAPI otherFunction
```

The documentation for `par` says that it `Indicates that it may be beneficial to evaluate the first argument in parallel with the second`.

- Does this work with IO?
- Can I get any more guaranteed than "it may be beneficial?"
- Or if I want greater guarantees will I need to use an `MVar` and `liftIO . forkIO`?

If I evaluate `a` first, I think I can use [`eitherT`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/either/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#v:eitherT) to check if `a` succeeded. But if I evaluate both at the same time I get confused. Here is the situation:

- If only `a` failed, I will retry `a`, if that fails I will run a function that manually reverses `b`
- If only `b` failed, I will retry `b`, write to the log in `RWS` and return `left`
- if both fail write to the log in `RWS` and return `left`
- if both succeed process `c` (which is not as time sensitive as `a` or `b`)

But if I evaluate both in parallel, then how can I identify which one failed? If I use `eitherT` immediately after `a` then `a` will evaluate first. If I use it after `b` then I won't be able to tell which one failed.

Is there a way I can evaluate the IO calls in parallel but respond differently depending on which one (if any) fails? Or am I left with a choice of parallelism vs failure mitigation?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to log when something important *starts* (or needs to be done), since, when it fails, it might be in some catastrophic manner such that logging is no longer possible. If it fails, you can easily (and automatically) find those things that were started whose outcomes are uncertain. If you only log when they *fail* you may have failures or partial successes that you never knew about.

Comment: Each of the API calls do their own pre/post logging. But because I don't want to waste too much time writing to the file system the log is just kept in memory until certain checkpoints. So if there's a critical failure I'd lose a chunk of the logs anyway.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Concurrently` applicative from the `async` package, or its generalized version from `lifted-async` that can work with `RWST IO`? Unwrap the actions using `eitherT`, execute them concurrently putting the results in a tuple, and then pattern-match on the tuple of `Either` values to decide what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are looking for will use `forkIO` and `MVar`s.

#### par

`par` is for [multiprocessor parallelism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parallelism), it helps evaluate terms in parallel. It doesn't help with `IO`. If you do

```
do
  a <- (someProcess :: IO a)
  ...
```

By the time you reach `...` everything from the `IO` action has happened (if we ignore evil lazy IO) to a point that `a` can be determined entirely by ordinary evaluation. This means that by the time you do `b <- someOtherProcess`, all of `someProcess` is already done. It's too late to do anything in parallel.

#### EitherT

You can explicitly examine the `Either e a` result of an `EitherT e m a`. `runEitherT :: EitherT e m a -> m (Either e a)` makes the success or failure explicit in the underlying monad. We can `lift` that right back into `EitherT` to make a computation that always succeeds (sometimes with an error) from one that sometimes fails.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

examine :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => EitherT e m a -> t m (Either e a)
examine = lift . runEitherT
```

#### forkIO

The simplest solution for doing two things in `IO` is `forkIO`. It starts another lightweight thread that you can forget about.

If you run a value with your transformer stack, there will be four pieces of data when you are done. The state `ConnectState`, the written `ConnectWriter` log, whether the computation was successful, and, depending on whether or not it was successful, either the value or the error.

```
EitherT String (RWST ConnectReader ConnectWriter ConnectState IO) a
^       ^                          ^             ^                ^
```

If we write out the structure of this, it looks like

```
(RWST ConnectReader ConnectWriter ConnectState IO) (Either String a)
                    ^             ^                 ^      ^      ^
ConnectReader -> ConnectState -> IO (Either String a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter)
                                     ^      ^      ^  ^             ^
```

All four of those pieces of information end up in the result of the `IO` action. If you fork your stack, you need to decide what to do with all of them when you join the results back together. You have already decided that you want to explicitly handle the `Either String a`. The `ConnectWriter`s can probably be combined together with `<>`. You will need to decide what to do with `ConnectState`.

We'll make a `fork` that returns all four of these pieces of data by shoving them into an `MVar`.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

forkConnectT :: ConnectT a -> ConnectT (MVar (Either String a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter))
forkConnectT cta = do
    result <- liftIO newEmptyMVar
    r <- lift ask
    s <- lift get
    liftIO $ forkIO $ do
        state <- runRWST (runEitherT cta) r s
        putMVar result state
    return result
```

Later, when we want the result, we can `try` and see if it is ready. We'll handle the `Either` for success and failure explicitly, while handling the state and writer behind the scenes.

```
import Data.Traversable

tryJoinConnectT :: MVar (Either String a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter) -> ConnectT (Maybe (Either String a))
tryJoinConnectT result = liftIO (tryTakeMVar result) >>= traverse reintegrate
```

Behind the scenes we `reintegrate` the `ConnectWriter` by telling this `ConnectT` to write what was accumulated in the other thread. You will need to decide what to do to combine the two states.

```
reintegrate :: (a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter) -> ConnectT a
reintegrate (a, s, w) = do
    -- Whatever needs to be done with the state.
    -- stateHere <- lift get
    lift $ tell w
    return a
```

If we want to wait until the result is ready, we can block reading the `MVar`. This offers less opportunity for handling errors such as timeouts.

```
joinConnectT :: MVar (Either String a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter) -> ConnectT (Either String a)
joinConnectT result = liftIO (takeMVar result) >>= reintegrate
```

#### Example

Putting it all together, we can fork a task in parallel, do something in this thread explicitly examining the success or failure, join with the result from the other thread, and reason about what to do next with explicit `Either`s representing success or failure from each process.

```
connectBoth :: ConnectT ()
connectBoth = do
    bVar <- forkConnectT $ connectAPI OtherAPI otherFunction
    a <- examine $ connectAPI SomeAPI someFunction
    b <- joinConnectT bVar 
    ...
```

#### Going farther

If you are paranoid, you will also want to handle exceptions (some of which can be handled by [`forkFinally`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkFinally)) and [asynchronous exceptions](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/general-haskell/exceptions/catching-all-exceptions). You will need to decide whether to [bundle these exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752900/exceptions-and-monad-transformers) into your stack or treat `IO` like it can always throw exceptions.

Consider using [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) instead of `forkIO` and `MVar`s.

[monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) (which you already have dependencies on via [either](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either)) provides mechanisms for building up, one transformer at a time, the type that represents the state of a monad transformer stack. We wrote this by hand as `(Either String a, ConnectState, ConnectWriter)`. If you are going to grow your transformer stack, you might want to get this from `MonadTransControl` instead. You can [restore the state from the forked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704615/monadbasecontrol-how-to-lift-threadgroup/27711006#27711006)(see MonadBaseControl section) in the parent to inspect it. You will still need to decide how to deal with the data from the two states..